# .htaccess config for search bot crawling

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Am build a web app with angularjs and my public root looks like this

```
 -assets
-snapshots
-snapshots/article/
-snapshots/sections/
-snaphosts/index.html
.htaccess
```

and am using phantomjs to generate snapshots from siteamp, my htaccess look this like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # angular seo
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1 [NC,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

when i try to test the snapshots using the url `http://xyx.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/section/news` i get `http://xyx.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/section/news#!/` instead of `http://xyx.com/snapshots/section/news.html` as expected.
I figure my .htaccess config could be wrong, am not really good at htaccess configs.
Any help will be appreciated.